# Perl Mason custom package access

Tags: perl, mason

I've a pure perl service class PlainData that retrieves some plain data from a remote file system. The package PlainData that produces some text, and a status flag (error, warning). How can I (put, link) it into a perl mason web context. I would do something like this:

```
<%init>
use PlainData;
my $stn = $ARGS{"STN"};
my $yr  = $ARGS{"YR"};
my $mo  = $ARGS{"MO"};
my $dy  = $ARGS{"DY"};
...do something with $stn,$yr,$mo,$dy,
my $plainDataHandler = new PlainData(); 
my ($status, $text) = $plainDtaHandler->listStationsByDay( $stn, $yr, $mo, $dy); 
if ($status>10) {
  print "<h1>ERROR REQUEST DATA STATIONS</h1>\n";
  print $text;
} else {
  print $text;
}
</%init>
```

I'v tried also

```
my $plainDataHandler = $m->comp('/var/perl/PlainData.pm');
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
% if($status>10) {
<h1>ERROR REQUEST DATA STATIONS</h1>
% }
<% $text %>

% #some link
<a href="/some/url"><% $text %></a>

<%init>
...
my ($status, $text) = $plainDtaHandler->listStationsByDay( $stn, $yr, $mo, $dy);
</%init>
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. But the script works with the print statements. The focus of the question was on the use statement. The PlainData class will be present in the script, if I use the perlOptions -I switch in the apache config.  But the cache ignores any corrections of PlainData.pm when I've started the apache service.